# delay navbar rendering until http return

Tags: angularjs

Our single page app load personal menu tree from a $http call.

I use the recursive template to render the menu. it appears the page is rendered before menu retrieved from server. How Can I make the page render wait until menu data arrives ?

code simplified for easy read

```
<body ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree-renderer.html">
     <a href="">{{menuItem.title}}</a>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItem.children" ng-include="'tree-renderer.html'></li>
     </ul>
    </script>
</body>

app.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.menuItems = [];
    $scope.loadMenu = function() {
       $http.get('../service/entitlement/myMenu', {params: {user: 'userId'}}).success(function(root) {
          $scope.menuItems = root.children;
       });
    };

    $scope.loadMenu();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the entire navbar in a div with the following:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper" ng-if="menuItems.length > 0"></div>
```

This way the navbar won't show until the menuItems object has been filled.

Comment: or just `ng-if="menuItems.length"`

Comment: Sure that works, but I prefer more explicit semantics. What ben really should be doing is removing the `$scope.menuItems = [];` line, and just have `ng-if="menuItems"`